# Использование кавычек в определении

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, переводы

1) **"Аква" - слово греческое, переводится оно как "вода".**
Обязательно ли или факультативно в данном предложении использование кавычек?

Если немного изменить предложение: 2) **Аква - слово греческое, по-русски - вода**, понадобиться ли употреблять кавычки?

И какое из двух определений более грамотно, удачно составлено?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Аква" происходит от латинского слова aqua – вода.

Аqua – слово латинское, переводится как *вода*

В русском языке нет самостоятельного слова *аква*, а латинское (или греческое?) слово не записывается русскими буквами.

Выделять этот элемент в русской записи как-то надо: кавычками или курсивом.

Comment: А если даём определение самостоятельному слову? Например. Евангелие - слово греческое, переводится как благая весть. Здесь нужны кавычки?

Comment: Евангелие - слово греческое, переводится как "благая весть".  Слово "евангелие" - греческое. Вместо кавычек в обоих случаях лучше использовать курсив, так как кавычки могут иметь дополнительное значение (кроме выделительного). . А вообще говоря, по этой теме существуют не правила, а рекомендации, например: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=курсивом

Answer (score 0):

В русском языке слова «аква» нет, а в вашем примере, очевидно, оно является кириллической записью **латинского (!)** *aqua* 'вода', поэтому постановка кавычек ***обязательна***.

> «Аква» — латинское слово, значащее «вода».

В печатном тексте также возможно выделение курсивом.